# Invoking different methods in python

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

Okay so I have the following:

```
Class OwnableObject(MobileObject):
   def __init__(self, name):
      MobileObject.__init__(self, name)
      self.owner = None # not owned

   def is_ownable(self): return True
   def is_owned(self): return self.owner
```

What is the difference between invoking the is_ownable method on OwnableObject
and invoking the is_ownable method on a MobileObject.

Comment: I pressume that is a general programming question, not Python-specific. You should read about classes and inheritance in some text on object-oriented programming.

Comment: 123, see my edited answer below. Since there doesn't appear to be a definition of `is_ownable` for `MobileObject` here, you can't do this: `mo = MobileObject(); mo.is_ownable()`. The result would be an error. My answer shows how to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Based on the code you have posted now, it's impossible to call `is_ownable` on a `MobileObject` because the `MobileObject` doesn't appear to have a definition for `is_ownable`.

If it does, then the difference is simply the difference between `MobileObject`'s definition and `OwnableObject`'s definition. I've updated the terms of the below to illustrate what I mean.

If you create a class in Python (or in any language, really):

```
class MobileObject(object):
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = position
    def move(self, position):
        self.position = position
    def is_ownable(self):
        return False
```

And then create a subclass:

```
class OwnableObject(MobileObject):
    def __init__(self, position, owner=None):
        MobileObject.__init__(self, position)
        self.owner = owner
    def is_ownable(self):
        return True
    def is_owned(self):
        return self.owner
```

The resulting subclass automatically inherits the methods of its superclass:

```
movable = MobileObject()
movable.is_ownable()       # returns False
movable.move(new_position) # moves movable
movable.is_owned()         # causes an error

ownable = OwnableObject()
ownable.is_ownable()       # returns True
ownable.move(new_position) # moves ownable
movable.is_owned()         # returns owner or None
```

As you can see, `is_ownable()` and `is_owned()` differ between the two classes -- and in the latter case, since `is_owned()` is not defined, it causes an error when called on `movable`. But `move()` works identically in both classes.

Comment: Posting multi-line code in a comment box doesn't really work, so I can't quite tell what you're asking. Could you edit your original question?

Comment: @Python123: Please edit your question if you have more to add. Unformated Python code without the line breaks and spaced can change everything.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it means the [same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) as in any programming language that supports the [object oriented paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming):

```
>>> class Base:
...     def ok(self):
...         print 'OK'
... 
>>> class SubClass(Base):
...     def oops(self):
...         print 'Oops'
... 
>>> x = SubClass()
>>> x.ok()
OK
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the methods implemented in the base class can be called on the subclass. The base implementation will be used unless you override the method in the subclass.